# gcc on macOS is running from /opt/local instead of /usr/bin

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

I was trying to upgrade my gcc version using brew and copying the new version file to usr/bin by using:

```
sudo ln -s  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0/bin/c++-9 /usr/bin/c++
sudo ln -s  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0/bin/g++-9 /usr/bin/g++
sudo ln -s  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0/bin/gcc-9 /usr/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0/bin/gcc-9 /usr/bin/cc
```

then I add the path to .bash_profile as below

```
PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0/lib:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

after all these done, I ran gcc -v, there is no change on version and I found the gcc it gave me was from /opt/local instead of usr/bin. Any idea about this situation? 
The terminal below is the gcc -v which computer gives me.

```
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16/5.4.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16
Configured with: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_bblocal_var_buildworker_ports_build_ports_lang_gcc5/gcc5/work/gcc-5.4.0/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin16 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,lto,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc5 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc5 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-5 --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-5 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc5/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-isl=/opt/local --enable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-build-config=bootstrap-debug --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --with-pkgversion='MacPorts gcc5 5.4.0_0'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 (MacPorts gcc5 5.4.0_0)
```

Comment: The PATH is searched *in order*. First match wins. This is in *no way* GCC specific/related.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this! So is it possible to delete gcc related files in opt/local?@JesperJuhl

Comment: "is it possible to delete gcc related files in opt/local?" - Of course it is *possible*. It is possible to delete *any* file on your machine. Is it a good idea? That's a very different question and I don't want to speak to that. But, if you want your custom GCC to be preferred, just put it's install location first in the path.

Comment: Since you already went through the trouble of adding simlinks to usr/bin, why did you add the full path to PATH?
Also, did you reload the terminal or "source ~/.bash_profile" before running "gcc -v"?

Comment: It's really poor practice and generally a **bad idea** to modify `/usr/bin`. Your OS vendor/supplier almost certainly expects to find specific versions of its tools there when upgrading/running/installing anything. Also, your OS vendor will certainly feel perfectly entitled to delete/overwrite or replace anything in there. You are asking for trouble. If you want to alter or customise your system-wide binaries locally, the place to do it is `/usr/local/bin`. YMMV but that would be my advice.